# TabNavigator working with conditionals

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am wondering if there is any way to have conditionals over TabNavigator. For example one user will see 4 tabs and the other one will see 3 only.

Here is my function where I try to implement this.

```
export const SignedIn = TabNavigator(
  {
    'Jobs': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        JobListScreen: { screen: JobList },
        JobItemScreen: { screen: JobItem },
        JobDetailsScreen: { screen: JobDetails },
        EditJobScreen: { screen: EditJob },
        BusinessProfileScreen: { screen: BusinessProfile },
        UserProfileScreen: { screen: UserProfile }
      })
    },
    'Search': {
      screen: SearchBar
    },
    'New Job': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        NewJobScreen: { screen: NewJob },
      })
    },
    'Profile': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        Profile: {screen: Profile},
        EditProfileScreen: { screen: EditProfile}
      })
    }
  }
)
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap it in an if statement like this:

```
if(someconditional) {

const SignedIn = TabNavigator(
  {
    'Jobs': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        JobListScreen: { screen: JobList },
        JobItemScreen: { screen: JobItem },
        JobDetailsScreen: { screen: JobDetails },
        EditJobScreen: { screen: EditJob },
        BusinessProfileScreen: { screen: BusinessProfile },
        UserProfileScreen: { screen: UserProfile }
      })
    },
    'Search': {
      screen: SearchBar
    },
    'New Job': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        NewJobScreen: { screen: NewJob },
      })
    },
    'Profile': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        Profile: {screen: Profile},
        EditProfileScreen: { screen: EditProfile}
      })
    }
  }
)

} else {
const SignedIn = TabNavigator(
  {
    'Jobs': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        JobListScreen: { screen: JobList },
        JobItemScreen: { screen: JobItem },
        JobDetailsScreen: { screen: JobDetails },
        EditJobScreen: { screen: EditJob },
        BusinessProfileScreen: { screen: BusinessProfile },
        UserProfileScreen: { screen: UserProfile }
      })
    },
    'Search': {
      screen: SearchBar
    },
    'Profile': {
      screen: StackNavigator({
        Profile: {screen: Profile},
        EditProfileScreen: { screen: EditProfile}
      })
    }
  }
)
}
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. How I couldn't think about it? I was thinking to use conditional on the tab only. Thanks

Comment: If you look at my [latest question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50965592/sorting-data-tables-from-two-json-structures) on here, it took me two days to figure out the needle / haystack routine, point is, it happens to all of us. Just needs a fresh set of eyes to give you a hand. :)

Comment: No worries, glad I could help. :)